# Difference between std::promise lvalue reference vs rvalue reference

Tags: multithreading, c++11, promise, future

My understanding is if we call get on future obtained from promise then it will wait till set_value is called and if that is never called program will wait forever but somehow this behavior is not working when I am using promise rvalue reference (it is throwing broken promise future error) though same is working with lvalue reference(wait forever). Any reasoning for this because i believe it should wait forever in case of rvalue reference also ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
void calculateValue(std::promise<int> &&p)
//void calculateValue(std::promise<int> &p) //uncomment this it will wait
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  std::cout<<"This is start of thread function "<<std::endl;
  //Do long operations
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
 // p.set_value(8);
  std::cout<<"This is end of thread function "<<std::endl;

}
int main() {

  std::promise<int> p;
  auto  fut = p.get_future();
  std::thread t(calculateValue,std::move(p));
  //uncomment this it will wait
  //std::thread t(calculateValue,std::ref(p);
  std::cout<<"main function ..."<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"value is "<<fut.get()<<std::endl;
  t.join();
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use this form of `thread`'s constructor:

```
std::thread t(calculateValue, std::move(p));
```

then, internally, `p` is moved from into a temporary object of `std::promise`. This temporary is used as an argument of `calculateValue` **independently** of its argument type:

```
void calculateValue(std::promise<int> &&p) // option #1
void calculateValue(std::promise<int> p)   // option #2
```

Before the thread finishes its execution, the temporary (or `p` parameter in the second case) is destroyed and this triggers `std::future_error`, since the shared state is not ready (`set_value` has not been invoked).

However, if you use the `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
std::thread t(calculateValue, std::ref(p));
```

then, the original promise is not moved from, it still exists and its destructor is not called until the end of `main`. Which is never reached, since the main thread will wait on `fut.get()`.

---

*Bottom line:* The problem is not at all related to the form of the parameter of `calculateValue`. Its about whether you do or do not move from `p` into a temporary, which, effectively, defines whether a destructor of a promise connected to the future (and their shared state) is or is not destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `std::move(p)` you effectively relinquish ownership of `p` to the thread. The promise `p` in the `main` function doesn't have any future, so to say.

When you pass a reference (with `std::ref`) then you still own the promise, and the thread function just have a reference to the promise in your `main` function. It's similar to passing a pointer to the variable `p`.

That's the reason your program will not be able to wait when moving the promise, but does wait as it should when passing a reference.

Comment: std::move(p) just did a static_cast and converted it into rvalue which is captured by rvalue reference so could not understand how it relinquish ownership when no move constructor is called